# Can't communicate with Glassfish server using HTTPS

Tags: https, glassfish, localhost, httplistener

I got Glassfish 4.0 running in my local machine. So I've added an http listener this way:

```
asadmin> create-http-listener --listeneraddress 127.0.0.1 --listenerport 80 --securityenabled=true --default-virtual-server server --listener_id 0
```

`securityenabled=true` should allow me to access my local host through httpS. However, when I try to access `https://localhost:80/`, my browsers tells me the webpage isn't avaliable. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The standard port for HTTPS is 443, not 80. It is a good idea to still listen on port 80, then redirect non SSL traffic to port 443 to avoid your end users getting errors if they forget to explicitly type `https://` when they visit your site.

If your browser still tells you the webpage isn't available, you will need to check that GlassFish is actually listening on that port (check that it can actually bind to it and you don't have a web server (apache, nginx) already bound).

The more common approach to this would be to proxy requests to GlassFish through a web server which can load balance between multiple instances.